# Color as background using rgb codes that will constantly change according to time

Tags: vb.net, colors, background

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = TimeOfDay
        Label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyy")
        Me.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & DateAndTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"))
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.White
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.White
    End Sub
End Class
```

In my code above, the background color changes to a hex color code depending on what the time is. However, I would like to change this because the colors that come with these codes are too dark.

Instead I am looking for the code to make the background color the % in red, green, and blue containers. (RGB colors)

For ex, if the time is 11:22:33, then I would like the background color to be 11% red, 22% green and 33% blue. Does this make sense? I am a beginner, and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to interpolate between 0 and 255 and use the interpolated value as either red, green or blue value, instead of using the time component directly, if you want to use the full color range. This is because the color components are represented 1 Byte each.

You basically stretch your 0-24 hours to values of 0-255, where Hour=0 corresponds to Red=0 and Hour=24 corresponds to Red=255.

```
Dim R As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Hour / 23 * 255)
```

This is quite similar to your "11% Red" approach.
The other parts would be defined similar,

```
Dim G As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Minute / 59 * 255)
Dim B As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Second / 59 * 255)
```

The linear interpolation formula in general is

```
New_Value = (Value - Min) / (Max - Min) * (New_Max - New_Min) + New_Min
```

Here Min and New_Min is 0, which simplifies the formula somewhat.

To actually assign the color you don't need to set it through construction of a HTML color. You simply can use the `Color.FromArgb` function. Just type it in in Visual Studio. For some reason IntelliSense (the feature that shows you what methods there are available while typing in the IDE) hides the function in some cases.

```
Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B)
```

This is nothing different than your HTML approach, just simpler (the `#321224` value is just a representation of three bytes in hexadecimal, in the form of `#RRGGBB`).

---

In the strictest sense the answer above is not exactly what you wanted to use. To use your percentage based approach you would construct the RGB values as

```
Dim R As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Hour / 100 * 255)
Dim G As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Minute / 100 * 255)
Dim B As Byte = CByte(Date.Now.Second / 100 * 255)
```

but this would not yield you the full color range as well (even 59% of 255 is only 150, so you would never see values between 150 and 255). Linear interpolation is the way to go.